# Birth certificate for non-indian citizens

Tags: india, birth-certificate

I was wondering if a child born to non-Indian parents during a travel to India will have the right to request a birth certificate from Indian authorities years after he/she was born?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The birth certificate would be a permanent public record in the Indian vital statistics record keeping office (by whatever name it went) where the person was born and the person identified in it could obtain a copy for a small certification fee.

Comment: This is a separate follow up but by any chance, do you know where one can read on the actual procedure to request the certificate?

Comment: @Newbie I don't. But it would probably depend upon which office in the government of India and its subdivisions it was issued in. It is entirely possible and indeed likely that the details of the procedure are different in different parts of India. I would look for the webpage of the state or local government in the place where the person was born to figure it out or to get a phone number for someone who could tell you.